# Symfony 2 Doctrine MS SQL Error

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have started working on a Symfony 2.3 project where I need to convert a financial website written in classic Asp to Php.

The client has Ms-Sql database which is to be used with Symfony 2.3 and doctrine, I have made the database and loaded the empty tables from the schema files.

Now whenever i try to generate entities from the database(Ms-Sql) I get the following error:

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
>   Unknown database type timestamp requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2008Platform may not support it

Does anyone know how to solve the problem or what should I do to avoid such a situation?

Kindly help me as I am new to Symfony 2.3, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your own types following doctrine doc about the subject :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

this is concerning enum type but you can use it with any type like timestamp and link it to string type or whatever other supported type by your database which fit you best.

## src/My/Project/MyProjectBundle.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('timestamp','string');
}
```

and normally all your timestamp types should be translated as string.

Comment: useful for me in case of `doctrine:schema:validate` that fail for a datetime2: `Unknown database type datetime2 requested, Realestate\MssqlBundle\Platforms\DblibPlatform`

Comment: @Nawfal Serrar In your solution you are suggesting tweaks in the code during making a connection or fetching data.

Comment: I have to generate entities from the database tables by writing the following command in the console : php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle yml

Comment: at this point entities are not generated and doctrine shows the error that I have posted in my question. how to solve this ?

Comment: @Robin you added the function that i posted to your AcmeBlogBundle.php before the mapping:import?

Comment: oh sorry I used it in controller my apologies

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't help there, the whole purpose of that function is executed at when the your app starts loading bundles and therefore execute the boot to add the timestamp datatypee as string

Answer (score 0):

**The configuration below works on Synfony 3.2**

1) in config.yml add the new type under types and map it under mssql connection

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            timestamp:  AppBundle\Type\Timestamp
..
..

        connections:
            mssql:
                driver:   sqlsrv
                host:     "%mssql_host%"
                port:     "%mssql_port%"
                dbname:   "%mssql_db_name%"
                user:     "%mssql_user%"
                password: "%mssql_password%"
                mapping_types:
                    timestamp: timestamp
```

2) Create the class AppBundle\Type\Timestamp as for the following url:

https://github.com/mmerian/doctrine-timestamp/blob/master/lib/DoctrineTimestamp/DBAL/Types/Timestamp.php

3) generate entities from the database with the following command:

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --em=mssql